# GraphQL: Modeling evolving types / state transitions

Tags: api, graphql, api-design, state-machine

This is an issue we have ran into multiple times now... very much looking forward to others' opinions!

---

**Scenario Description** (for illustration purposes):

Somebody visits our website, perhaps they fill out some forms, whatever. To us, this person is a prospect/lead. They have not been fully onboarded as a customer; they are simply a *potential* future customer.

Certain actions can be performed on these `Prospects`, such as adding certain data to their profile. Let's call this `add_foobar_data`. Of course, if they become a *real* customer (somebody consuming our service), we still need to be able to add/remove said data from their account.

---

**Scenario** (tl;dr):

- `Prospects` can become `Customers`
- Mutation `add_foobar_data` *conceptually* applies to both `Prospects` and `Customers`
- `Prospects` only have a subset of data of `Customers` (they are a true subset; currently `Customers` have a lot of non-nullable fields `Prospects` do not have)

---

**Options**:

1. Create a union type, e.g. `Customerable`. `add_foobar_data` would return a `Customerable` (or backref to a `Customerable`) rather than a specific type.
2. Create separate mutations for modifying `Prospects` and `Customers` (`add_foobar_data_to_prospect`, `add_foobar_data_to_customer`)
3. Everybody is a `Customer`! Make all those non-nullable fields on `Customer` that are not in `Prospect` nullable and add a new flag called `isProspect` (or `isDraft` if we want to change how we think about the flow).
4. *Perhaps some other approach I did not think of...*

---

Anybody have thoughts on what is the best approach to this situation and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an [Interface](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) since `Prospect` is a direct subset of `Customer`, and not by coincidence.